# Render partial in railway.js

Tags: model-view-controller, node.js, partial-views, railway.js

I'm very new to node.js and I'm using the railway.js framework to learn MVC at the sametime. We use C# at work. I'm a front-end Dev.. I can't seem to figure out or see any documentation on how to render a partial view in railway properly. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in your view:

```
<%- partial('viewname') %>
```

It will use express2.0 lookup partial procudure. Hint: it it's your first steps with railwayjs, start with scaffold generator `railway generate crud post title content`

Check railway starter guide available at github: https://github.com/1602/express-on-railway/wiki/RailwayJS-starter-guide

Comment: Oh snap! That did it. Yeah I'm kinda building around the blog example. Just playing around to see how things work. Thanks for your help.